# SQL get all IDs where Sub-IDs are exactly specified without getting other IDs where some Sub-ID's are not present

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for that title, I don't know how to describe my problem in one sentence.

I have Table like this:

```
event | thema
-------------
1       1
1       2
2       1
2       2
2       3
3       1
3       2
3       3
3       4
4       1
4       2
4       3
```

What I want are the event IDs where the thema is exaclty 1, 2 and 3, not the event ID where it is only 1 and 2 or 1,2,3 and 4.

```
SELECT event WHERE thema=1 OR thema=2 OR thema=3
```

returns them all

```
SELECT event WHERE thema=1 AND thema=2 AND thema=3
```

returns nothing.

I think this should be absolutely simple, but stack is overflown...

Thanks for some help!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of query is a "set-within-sets" query (your are looking for sets of "thema" for each event).  The most general approach is aggregation using a `having` clause.  This might be the shortest way to write the query using standard SQL:

```
select event
from table t
group by event
having count(distinct (case when thema in (1, 2, 3) then thema end)) = 3;
```

Comment: this looks doable within the context, i'll try that out!

Answer (score 2):

Group by the `event` and take only those having at least one `thema` 1 and 2 and 3 and not any other

```
SELECT event 
from your_table
group by event
having sum(case when thema = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when thema = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when thema = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
and sum(case when thema not in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

or,

first create table `@themas` (depending on vendor, make this a temp table or a simple table-valued variable) that contains user-specified list of thema values, then

```
Select event from your_table y
Where not exists 
      (Select * From @Themas t
       where Not Exists
           (Select * From your_table 
              where event = y.event
                  and thema = t.thema))
   and not exists (Select * From your_table 
                  where event = t.event
                     and thema not in 
                        (Select thema From @Themas ))
```

Comment: Let's say that the selected themas come from a user-interface, so there can be only one or two themas or even more than 3 themas selected.